# Model Binding an object with a member that is IParsable

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a method in my ASP.NET controller that expects a `Foo` instance:

```
public ActionResult CreateFoo([FromBody] Foo foo);
```

`Foo` has a property `Bar`, which requires custom parsing. So I have Bar implement IParsable, like so:

```
class Bar : IParsable<Bar>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static bool TryParse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider, out Bar result) 
    {
         result = new Bar { Value = s };
         return true;
    }

    public Bar Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider) => new Bar { Value = s };
}
```

I call the controller above with the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "Bar": "hello!"
}
```

So I expect the model binder to resolve a instance of Foo with Bar.Value = "hello!". However, right now, I'm getting the error **"The JSON value could not be converted to Bar. Path: $.bar"**

Why isn't this working? The Learn article on model binding says that implementing IParsable would be enough, but it isn't clear if nested objects will also support using TryParse. I really hope I can avoid writing a custom binder.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I come back to ASP.NET I realize I forgot something...

The model binder is mapping the class listed in the controller (in this case, `Foo`) to a serializer, which, by default, is going to be the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`. So, what I need is not to control the model binding, but the (de)serialization.

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o =>
    {
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new BarConverter());
    });

// -----------------------------

internal class BarJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Bar>
{
    public override Bar? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => Bar.Parse(reader.GetString()!, null);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Bar value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => writer.WriteStringValue(value.Value);
}
```

More examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0).